# Is there a way to schedule airplane mode for iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, airplane-mode

This question was essentially asked 3+yrs prior, but I don't see any recent updates.   I'd like to set my iphone to engage airplane mode for an hour (example) and then turn off airplane mode/engage cellular service an hour later.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using a Shortcut for that would probably be the best solution. If you have any experience with programming you could probably whip something up without too much effort, or I'd recommend checking out [the shortcuts subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/).

There's also a chance somebody has already created what you're looking for, I didn't find anything in a quick glance through this [gallery](https://shortcutsgallery.com/siri-shortcuts/?_search=airplane%20mode), but you could possibly find something with some digging.

I hope this helps move you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

No - this isn’t automated. Either to engage or to disengage airplane settings. You’ll want to toggle it the usual way when needed.